# Python cprofile filename:lineno get full path

Tags: python, cprofile

I use `cprofile` to get high offenders, however the `filename:lineno` is only listing the filename, but having the filepath listed would be more usefull to quickly open that path. Especially if there might be same module nams in different hierarchies.

```
ncalls    tottime    percall    cumtime    percall    filename:lineno(function)
1         0.000       0.000       3.922    display.py:599 (show)
```

Is there an option to turn that into fullpath?

Answer (score 7):

I guess you format the output with "pstats.Stats" class and you have:

```
stats = Stats(profiler)
stats.strip_dirs()  # remove this
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I was just brainlessly copying the sample from from: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual

Comment: What if cProfiler is getting run from terminal?

Answer (score 5):

If you are running from terminal, add -o flag:

```
python -m cProfile -o output.data your_script.py ...
```

Then from the console:

```
import pstats
ps = pstats.Stats('output.data')
ps.sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.CUMULATIVE).print_stats(20)
```

You should get an output like:

```
Tue Oct 19 07:17:56 2021    output.data

         18646457 function calls (18374990 primitive calls) in 30.760 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 22652 to 20 due to restriction <20>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   4321/1    0.037    0.000   30.796   30.796 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000   30.796   30.796 manage.py:1(<module>)
      ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a built in way but you can do this:

```py
import cProfile                                                    
import pstats   
                                                   
p = cProfile.Profile()                      
s = p.run("1+1")     
pstats.Stats(s).sort_stats(2).print_stats()
```